# Debugging wifi disconnects

Tags: wifi, power

I'm trying to debug why my GoPro disconnects from my Raspberry Pi's wifi in AP mode. It seems that the GoPro is rather sensitive to network conditions, so if there's any weak signal, it will drop the connection. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the GoPro's wifi client so I have to work with what it is.

I have tried a number of different boards and have found that a Jetson Nano + Intel AC8265 provides a stable enough connection. Additionally, it seems that with that combination, I'm able to get a substantially stronger signal of about -30 dBm compared to the Raspberry Pi at -40 dBm when measured with an Android phone. Both of these numbers are strong, however I suspect the disconnects are due to intermittent fluctuations and the Raspberry Pi is much more likely to drop below the GoPro's tolerance.

Originally, I had thought that the problem was perhaps that wifi radio itself was underpowered, so I also tried using a FriendlyElec Nano Pi which accepts an external antenna but it also has similar issues. I also tried connecting an Intel AC8260 to the Nano Pi via the M.2 hat + a converter, but that also didn't boost the signal.

In all cases, I'm running a 5 GHz AP with the same config and have not modified the tx power or anything like that. Does anyone have any thoughts to how I might be able to debug this further? Is this really due to the wifi radio being underpowered like I suspect or might there be another reason the Jetson Nano is able to transmit an appreciably more stable signal than the Raspberry Pi or Nano Pi?

The GoPro has no issues maintaining a connection with my home router, so I'm looking for a way to replicate that signal strength on an SBC.

Comment: Have you tried 2.4Ghz?  I've not had much luck with any Pi in 5GHz WiFi - also what AP config did you use?  The one on the RPF site was most stable for me.

Comment: I have, 2.4GHz was also not stable enough. I've been using the one on the RPF guide as well. Although curiously, 2.4GHz was more stable when connecting other devices such as my laptop to the AP. I suspect this has to do with the GoPro's seemingly very low tolerance for dropped packets.